# Why is my datagridview.rowfilter not working. I keep getting a syntax error message

Tags: c#, ado.net, datagridview, rowfilter

My application has a populated datatable and binds it to a ddatagridview by setting the datasource property.

At run time I want to filter this table. When the user clicks a button I run the following code:

```
dataManager.VDMSTables.DataTable.DefaultView.RowFilter = column + " LIKE '%" + criteria + "%'";
```

All the classes are populated correctly. At runtime when I reach this line I get the following error message:

Syntax error: Missing operand after 'Data' operator. The variables that I use to build the rowfilter are correctly populated. Even when I hard code a string I still get this same error. Why?

Comment: Do you have an example criteria value that's causing the issue?  I'm assuming column is a string and not a Column object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does the actual string you're constructing look like when you view it in the debugger?  The word "Data" doesn't show up in there, does it?

If so, then it's telling you that Data is a reserved word and you need to mark it as such.  As in:

```
dataManager.VDMSTables.DataTable.DefaultView.RowFilter 
    = String.Format("[{0}] LIKE '%{1}%'"
        , column
        , YourSingleQuoteEscape(criteria) );
```

That will produce:

```
"[Data] like '%strawberries%'"
```

... which should parse correctly for your RowFilter.

Comment: No it doesn't. Even when I hard code the string to something such as

    string s = "column name  = 'test'" I get that error.

then i use this string s as the row filter iike so:
 
    dataview.rowfilter = s;

Comment: I'v eseen the stirng.Format method used on some of the online posts. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Why then do you think that this line is the source of your problem?  If you can set .RowFilter = "mycol like 'fishies'" and it still throws,then your next step is to remove the line entirely and see what happens.  My suspicion is it will then throw on whatever line happened to float up to the same position.  In other words, look at the lines above and below.